# Minha aplicação não dá erro, mas não aparece nada na tela(xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, cross-platform

Desenvolvendo e aprendendo xamarin. Peguei um exemplo do Macoratti e resolvi implementar, pois se trata de consumo de REST com xamarin. Fiz tudo conforme está no site do autor e quando rodo, não aparece nada em meu smartphone(samsung J5). Quando eu deixo a primeira `StackLayout` que é um label, ela aparece. Mas as demais `StackLayout` não mostra nada. Dentro da primeira stack, eu coloquey um componente `Entry` junto com o label, apareceu, mas o placeholder ficou cortado pela metade horizontalmente, ou seja, apenas a metade de baixo aparecia. Coloco abaixo o meu código:
MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Teste2"
             x:Class="Teste2.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackLayout Padding="5,5,0,0">
            <Label Text="Adicionar um Produto" TextColor="Green" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,0">
            <Entry x:Name="txtNome" Placeholder="Nome do produto" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Entry x:Name="txtCategoria" Placeholder="Categoria do produto" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small" />
            <Entry x:Name="txtPreco" Placeholder="Preço do produto" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                    HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small" />
            <Button HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" Text="Adicionar/Atualizar Produto" 
                    Clicked="btnAdicionar_Clicked" FontSize="Small"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <!--<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10,5,10,0">
            <ListView x:Name="listaProdutos" ItemSelected="listaProdutos_ItemSelected" BackgroundColor="Aqua" SeparatorColor="Blue">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Clicked="OnAtualizar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Atualizar" />
                                <MenuItem Clicked="OnDeletar" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Deletar" IsDestructive="True" />
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10,10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Nome}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Categoria}" TextColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Preco}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>-->
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

App.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //MainPage = new Teste2.MainPage();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Teste2.MainPage());
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
```

**EDIT1**
Fiz isso e consigo ver meu Entry, mas o que escrevo ou o placeholder está cortado pela metade, ou seja, só leio a parte de baixo. Não consigo ler o texto todo. O que pode ser isso? Porém se crio mais de um `StackLayout`, aí não aparece nada no App. Parece que não está aceitando `StackLayout` aninhados.

```
StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,0">
            <!--<Label Text="Adicionar um Produto" TextColor="Green" />-->
                <Entry x:Name="txtNome" Placeholder="Nome do produto" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small"/>
            <Entry x:Name="txtCategoria" Placeholder="Categoria do produto" HorizontalOptions="Start" 
                    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="300" FontSize="Small" />
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Observei, agora no meu cel, que quando eu fecho e abro o meu app, dá essa mensagem: `O Teste2.Android parou`. Acho que o App esteja executando em parte, ou seja, ele faz a Implantação e para por aí, assim eu penso. Por isso não carrega na tela os componentes e por alguma razão, ele carrega apenas o label, mas mesmo assim dá uma demorada para exibir.

Comment: Criando os componentes pelo MainPage.xaml.cs(no construtor da classe), consigo visualizar e é até mais rápido a implantação. Só preciso ver agora, como criar oe eventos dos botões e viro essa página. Depois, quando eu estiver mais à vontade com o xamarin, volto para o xaml.

Comment: Quando eu retirei os eventos Clicked do botão e o evento ItemSelected do ListView, funcionou, ou seja, pude ver os componentes no meu Cel. Se coloco os eventos, aí não funciona. Fui no .cs e adicionei os eventos e mesmo assim, não funcionou. Fiz apenas com o botão assi: `private void btnAdicionar_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e){}`

Answer (score 2):

O problema foi resolvido. O que estava embaçando, era que tanto o botão quanto a ListView tinham eventos click e esses eventos estavam apenas declarados. Removendo a declaração do evento na MainPage.xaml, funciona, mas não consigo chamar um evento dessa forma, mas isso é para outro post.